# When I deselect the swatch once after selected, the product image is not displaying in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, product-images, migration

When I deselect the swatch once after selected the product image went **blank** when I inspected and the **image src** went undefined in Magento 2.2??

Comment: are u getting any error in console?

Comment: No I didn't get any error the src of the image is undefied. Any help would be appreciable. Looking forward to the response.

Comment: We have the same same problem, but in our case it depends on the input-type of the attributes of the configurable products. Creating configurable products using only swatches with input-type "dropdown" it works fine, but using attributes with "Visual Swatches" we also get the blank image-area. But we are still testing. Did you find out any helpful news about this issue?

Comment: @feelcomfort We didn't found any fix for this but we have auto selected the swatch and it can be de-selected anymore since it is and required one so the user must have to select any one of the swatch. Hence the bug won't be available in this case.

Comment: Have a look at this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221543/how-to-disable-a-swatch-once-it-is-been-selected-in-magento2-2/223476#223476

Comment: Did you fix this issue? If then can you please share the solution.