# How to disable a swatch, once it is been selected in Magento2.2?

Tags: magento2.2, swatches, color-swatches, configurable-swatches

I am trying to disable a swatch, once after it has been selected. So it should not be deselected...

How to do it in Magento2.2.x ?

Comment: I improved my answer slightly as was trying to figure out something about mixins hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to stop the swatch being unselected by overriding part of the core swatch-renderer.js. I use Amasty's Color Swatches Pro so I made the change to the swatch-renderer.js in that module.

I copied the widget...

> _OnClick: function ($this, $widget) {

and changed this section...

```
if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
 // COMMENT OUT THE 3 LINES BELOW TO PREVENT TOGGLING OF CURRENT SWATCH SELECTION
    //$parent.removeAttr('option-selected').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    //$input.val('');
    //$label.text('');
} else {
    $parent.attr('option-selected', $this.attr('option-id')).find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $label.text($this.attr('option-label'));
    $input.val($this.attr('option-id'));
    $this.addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: perfect @silkspin You really made my day

Comment: @silkspin I have implemented this solution, although now swatch remains selected but still I am getting undefined error upon selecting same selected swatch again. Can you please share a solution that image is not changed while selecting swatch?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with modifications to the `swatch-renderer.js`. Adding a couple of lines of code to the `_OnClick` event within here like below will **disable pointer events** and **drop the opacity** so the user knows it's disabled:

```
    $this.parent().css("pointer-events","none");
    $this.parent().css("opacity","0.6");
```

I would prefer to do this with a **mixin** which wraps the original function to maintain all original functionality from the call and only minor additional functionality is added.

## Create a Mixin to Overide Swatch Rendering

1. Create a new JS file to override the default `_OnClick` method within `swatch-renderer.js`. You could put this in your theme or module. Here i have put it within a theme.

   ```
   define([
       'jquery',
       'mage/utils/wrapper'
   ], function ($, wrapper) {
       'use strict';

       return function(swatchRenderer){

           var OnClickWrapper = wrapper.wrap(swatchRenderer.prototype._OnClick, function(originalSwatchRenderer){
               var result = originalSwatchRenderer();

               /*Custom code start*/
               $(arguments[1][0]).parent().css({"pointer-events":"none","opacity":"0.6"});
               /*Custom code end*/

               return result;
           });

           swatchRenderer.prototype._OnClick = OnClickWrapper;
           return swatchRenderer;
       };
   });
   ```

> app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/ThemeName/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer-mixin.js

2. Add a `requirejs-config.js` file to initalise the new mixin file:

   ```
   var config = {
   config: {
       mixins: {
           'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
               'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer-mixin': true
           }
       }
   }
   };
   ```

> app/design/frontend/ThemeVendor/ThemeName/Magento_Swatches/requirejs-config.js

Comment: This disabled the whole swatches.

Comment: In your situation the selector must be disabling the parent of all the swatches. Maybe try taking out .parent(). I did test this worked fine for me so should just be some minor tweaking required here.

Comment: I tried that too but all the swatches is disabled, if i click the any swatch then rest of the swatches should enabled. @harri and thank you so much the response. will keep on checking for it.

Comment: Assume there is two swatches, first one is always selected when the page gets rendered and yes that is disabled now and the only option for us to select is second swatch but when i click that both is in disabled state, since because the first already have been disabled. Isn't it..?? hope u get the scenario correctly.

Comment: Ok from what i can tell then the issue seems to be that the first one is disabled as it is automatically selected on page load and you want to remove this behavior (the autmoatic selection of first swatch)? For me nothing is selected by default for swatches within Magento is this some functionality that has been added?

Comment: I would check for modifications to swatch renderer that already exists / javascript that may be selecting that first swatch and we have to remove it. Normally the first swatch is blank like in this vanilla Magento 2 here: http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/deion-long-sleeve-evercool-trade-tee.html

Comment: If you have a site that i can access i can take a look over and see if i can track down what is causing this ?

Comment: No, on page load first swatch is selected and hence that is disabled by the above code and then I'll select the second one and yes that is disabled now once it is selected but first should opt for enabled now  but it is not.

Comment: http://streetstrider.enterpriseapplicationdevelopers.com:3000/streetstrider3i.html

Comment: Ill take a look when i get a chance. What page has 2 swatch options on?

Comment: Can I get any help on this..?? @harri

Comment: I need clearing up on what you want to happen.This does what the question asks however your site selects first swatch on page load. Do you want to stop the first swatch from being auto selected now?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, No it should auto select but should not de-select the swatch once clicked and when second swatch clicked it should de-select frist one and vice-versa

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran did you fix this issue? if, then can you please share the solution.

Answer (score 0):

\magento\app\code\Module\RewriteSwatches\etc\module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Module_RewriteSwatches" setup_version="2.0.1">
</module>
```

\magento\app\code\Module\RewriteSwatches\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
            'Module_RewriteSwatches/js/swatch-renderer': true
        }
    }
}};
```

\magento\app\code\Module\RewriteSwatches\registration.php

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,'Module_RewriteSwatches',__DIR__);
```

\magento\app\code\Module\RewriteSwatches\view\frontend\web\js\swatch-renderer.js

```
    define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    return function (widget) {
        $.widget('mage.SwatchRenderer', widget, {

        /**
         * Event for swatch options
         *
         * @param {Object} $this
         * @param {Object} $widget
         * @param {String|undefined} eventName
         * @private
         */
        _OnClick: function ($this, $widget, eventName) {
            var $parent = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass),
                $wrapper = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeOptionsWrapper),
                $label = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeSelectedOptionLabelClass),
                attributeId = $parent.attr('attribute-id'),
                $input = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput);

            if ($widget.inProductList) {
                $input = $widget.productForm.find(
                    '.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput + '[name="super_attribute[' + attributeId + ']"]'
                );
            }

            if ($this.hasClass('disabled')) {
                return;
            }

            if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
                //$parent.removeAttr('option-selected').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                //$input.val('');
                //$label.text('');
                //$this.attr('aria-checked', false);
            } else {
                $parent.attr('option-selected', $this.attr('option-id')).find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
                $label.text($this.attr('option-label'));
                $input.val($this.attr('option-id'));
                $input.attr('data-attr-name', this._getAttributeCodeById(attributeId));
                $this.addClass('selected');
                $widget._toggleCheckedAttributes($this, $wrapper);
            }

            $widget._Rebuild();

            if ($widget.element.parents($widget.options.selectorProduct)
                .find(this.options.selectorProductPrice).is(':data(mage-priceBox)')
            ) {
                $widget._UpdatePrice();
            }

            $(document).trigger('updateMsrpPriceBlock',
                [
                    parseInt($this.attr('index'), 10) + 1,
                    $widget.options.jsonConfig.optionPrices
                ]);

            $widget._loadMedia(eventName);
            $input.trigger('change');
        }
    });
    return $.mage.SwatchRenderer;
}
});
```