# Access Variables passed to a function modified/wrapped with a mixin

Tags: magento2, mixins

I want to tidy up this answer i gave here:

[How to disable a swatch, once it is been selected in Magento2.2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/221543/how-to-disable-a-swatch-once-it-is-been-selected-in-magento2-2/221578#221578)

Instead of completely overriding the function i would like to improve it by wrapping the original function call and adding my custom code after the original function like so:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function(swatchRenderer){

        var OnClickWrapper = wrapper.wrap(swatchRenderer.prototype._OnClick, function(originalSwatchRenderer){

            var result = originalSwatchRenderer();

            /*Custom code start*/
            console.log(this);
            //.css({"pointer-events":"none","opacity":"0.6"});
            alert("test");
            /*Custom code end*/

            return result;
        });

        swatchRenderer.prototype._OnClick = OnClickWrapper;
        return swatchRenderer;
    };
});
```

This is mostly functioning ok however want to access the parameters passed to the original function so i can grab the parent of the clicked element with `$this`:

```
_OnClick: function ($this, $widget, eventName)
```

Is it possible to access these from within the wrapper and and how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arguments` variable seemed to contain what i needed. After logging the object the specific element i needed seemed to be stored in: `arguments[1][0]`

## Final code:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';

    return function(swatchRenderer){

        var OnClickWrapper = wrapper.wrap(swatchRenderer.prototype._OnClick, function(originalSwatchRenderer){
            var result = originalSwatchRenderer();

            /*Custom code start*/
            $(arguments[1][0]).parent().css({"pointer-events":"none","opacity":"0.6"});
            /*Custom code end*/
            
            return result;
        });

        swatchRenderer.prototype._OnClick = OnClickWrapper;
        return swatchRenderer;
    };
});
```