# Magento 2.2.6, Configurable Products: Blank Image-Area after deselecting "visual swatch" on product-page

Tags: configurable-product, product-images, configurable-swatches, gallery-image, magento2.2.6

#### Preconditions

1. Update from Magento 2.2.4 to 2.2.6

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Add Product in the Backend
2. Create Configurations
4. Use Attributes with the input type "Visual Swatch"
3. Save Product
4. Open Product-page in the frontend
5. Select Attribute/Swatch --> Images-Gallery of the simple product appears
6. Deselect Attribute/Swatch

#### Expected result

1. Image-Gallery of the configurable product appears again
[image: expected_result]

#### Actual result

1. Product page with a blank image-area
[image: actual_result]

Does anyone have a solution/fix to this issue?
The only similar problem we found in web was a request without a solution, but 6 Month ago. Maybe it is not only a Magento 2.2.6 Bug: [When I deselect the swatch once after selected, the product image is not displaying in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215228/when-i-deselect-the-swatch-once-after-selected-the-product-image-is-not-display)

Another issue: In the past the swatch-images were saved and reloaded after changing to dropdown and back to visual-swatch. Since Mangento 2.2.6 the values are deleted and we need to reselect and upload them. In the filespace this leads to copies of the same image in the same folder.

Thanks for help.